# NLog file target - best performance for logging log files for Splunk Forwarder and avoid locks?

Tags: nlog

What's the best performance way of writing log files for Splunk forwarder (that monitors a folder and removes the files and puts them into Splunk)?

```
<target name="jsonfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${gdc:logDirectory}/${gdc:environment}/${longdate}.json" >
          <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
              <attribute name="time" layout="${date:format=O}" />
              <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
              <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}"/>
              <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
          </layout>
      </target>
```

Creates files like:
2021-08-25 18_37_45.9420.json
...

But that would mean a lot of files (every millisecond fraction). Plus if there are a lot of log activity, each log file could have more than one record (and possibly fight with the Forwarder for file locks).

I could even add a guid in the end of the file name so that I'm sure that only record logs per file, but again, that's a lot of files being created.

But if log fewer times (every second):

```
 <target name="jsonfile" xsi:type="File"
 fileName="${gdc:logDirectory}/${gdc:environment}/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.json"
           <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
               <attribute name="time" layout="${date:format=O}" />
               <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
               <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}"/>
               <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
           </layout>
   </target>
```

Creates a file like:
2021-08-25_18-41-31.json

...would possibly mean that Splunk and NLog would possibly fight over file locks.

What's the optimal performance way of logging files for the Splunk Forwarder? :-)

Comment: See also: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/What-s-the-optimal-best-performance-solution-for-creating-log/m-p/564787

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance#file-logging-performance (Configure `KeepFileOpen=true` + `concurrentwrites=false` for best performance).